# Failed to load plugin vue/Eslint breaking

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, eslint

all I cannot find why my vscode is constantly breaking with ESLint which cannot find vue somehow

`Error` :

```js
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to load plugin 'vue' declared in 'frontend/.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-vue'
```

Here's my `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    {"mode": "auto"}
  ],
}
```

`eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "eslint:recommended", "@vue/prettier"],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint",
  },
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "off" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "off" : "off",
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)", "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"],
      env: {
        mocha: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.7.0",
    "document-ready": "^2.0.2",
    "plotly.js-dist": "^2.6.2",
    "postscribe": "^2.0.8",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
    "vue-script-component": "^0.1.7",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.10",
    "vuetify-confirm-box": "^1.0.10",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-webdriverio": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "chromedriver": "^88",
    "eslint": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.1.0",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "geckodriver": "^1.20.0",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "sinon": "^12.0.1",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.7.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.3",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.3",
    "wdio-geckodriver-service": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

If anyone could point out what am I missing in my configuration would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you run npm i or yarn and try it again? seems like eslint-plugin-vue is not correctly added

Comment: Otherwise take a look at this, should hopefully help: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/976